# R: how can I do data[[k]] calculation

Tags: r, frequency, sample

I have a data set from a sample without replacement look like this:

[image: data.c]
[image: data.c]
[image: data.c]
The picture shows the frequency of each species, and there are 50 data.c[[k]] like this.
Now I'm trying the Jackknife resampling(without replacement) to estimate coverage, codes below:

```
data.c <- sapply(1:50, function(k)table(data[,k])) #freq
mdata <- sapply(1:50, function(k)sum(data.c[[k]]==1)) 
True_c <- 1- sum(np*(exp(lchoose(N-data.c[[k]], i))/exp(lchoose(N,i))))  
##True_c function shows error message##
```

my result shows "Error in N - data.c : non-numeric argument to binary operator"
I want to do True_c with N(population size) minus species' frequncies and do the 'lchoose' function, how can I do or adjust my codes?

My entire codes show below:

```
### without replacement
for (seed in c(99,100)){
  set.seed(seed)
    for (s in c(100,1000)){
      sdata <- rlnorm(s,0,1)
      p <- sdata/sum(sdata)
      gn <- p*s*10
      gn <- round(gn)
      M <-replace(gn, gn==0,1) #or M=gn[gn==0]=1
      N <- sum(M); N
      np <- M/N #new prob
      pop_index = rep(1:s, time=M)
      for (i in c(100,500,1000,5000,N))
        {
        data=replicate(50, sample(pop_index, i, 
                                    replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)) 
        data.c=sapply(1:50, function(k)table(data[,k])) #freq
        mdata=sapply(1:50, function(k)sum(data.c[[k]]==1)) #each group, total freq=1
        True_c <- 1- sum(np*(exp(lchoose(N-data.c, i))/exp(lchoose(N,i))))
        c.hat <- (1-(1-(i/N))*(mdata/i)) #geo
        bias=mean(c.hat)-True_c
        var=var(c.hat)
        cat("sample_size",i,"\n",
            "True_C=",True_c,"\n",
            "bias =",bias,"\n",
            "variance=",var,"\n","\n")
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You need to (at least) share the error message. A reproducible example (e.g., the output of `dput(data.c[1:3])`) would be even better.

Comment: @Roland I've edited my description, thank you for your advise.

Comment: `data.c` is a list. You can substract a list from a numeric value (like in `N - data.c`). It's not clear what you want to achieve, but you probably need another `sapply` loop.